# No motching primary or candidate keys

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a database in SQL Server and here's an issue I can't overcome:

```
create table Dzień(
  ID_konferencji int foreign key references Konferencje(ID_konferencji) not null,
  Data date not null,
  primary key(Data)
)

create table Warsztaty(
  ID_warsztatu int identity(1,1) primary key not null,
  ID_konferencji int foreign key references Konferencje(ID_konferencji) not null,
  **Data date foreign key references Dzień(Data) not null,**
  Nazwa nvarchar(50) not null,
  Godzina time(0) not null, 
  Cena money null
)
```

In bold line I get something like this:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Dzień' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key

( http://oi39.tinypic.com/f41utz.jpg )

Why is this happening? How can I get rid of that?

Comment: Ignore what IntelliSense tooltips are telling you at parse time. If it's really bugging you, try putting a `GO` between the two create table statements. And [please start using the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx).